# Trying to click link via selenium in java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Using selenium in java.  We have a series of links that look approximately like:

```
<a href='javascript:newWin("/ABC")'>ABC</a>
```

We're trying to click that link.  There's no id unfortunately.  We've tried a few things along the lines of the following.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//[contains(@href, 'javascript:newWin')])")).click();
```

Which results in:

> Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression
>   (//[contains(@href, 'javascript:newWin')]) because of the following
>   error: [object Error] (WARNING: The server did not provide any
>   stacktrace information)

We're trying to figure out how to XPath to that anchor, and click it.  We can't get an ID on it (at least not yet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='ABC']").click();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're XPATH is malformed, but you're on the right track. Try:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href, 'javascript:newWin')]")).click();
```